# Using Math.floor on a double variable won't work. Java (Using Eclipse)

Tags: java, variables, math, double

So basically I tried 2 things. I'll gives you the codes for them:

```
double number;
Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
System.out.println("Name a number!");
number = input.nextDouble();
number = Math.floor(number);
System.out.println(number);
```

and this one:

```
double number;
Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
System.out.println("Name a number!");
number = Math.floor(input.nextDouble());
System.out.println(number);
```

But they both don't seem to work... Can anybody help me with this? I basically want to round up the user's input. Is it possible to turn a double into an integer? For example: The console asks "How many fries do you want" then the user decides to be funny and say 4.5. This would give me an error. I want the console to automatically turn the 4.5 into 4.

EDIT: I don't know if this helps... But I only have 1 class and this is what the full class looks like:

```
package package.name;

import java.util.Scanner;
public class TestingJava
{
    public static void main(String[] args){
        double number;
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Name a number!");
        number = input.nextDouble();
        number = Math.floor(number);
        System.out.println(number);
    }
}
```

And this is the error I get whenever I type a number like 3.6:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.util.InputMismatchException
    at java.util.Scanner.throwFor(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.Scanner.next(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.Scanner.nextDouble(Unknown Source)
    at package.name.TestingJava.main(TestingJava.java:10)
```

When I give the number "2" it replies back "2.0" but when I make a fraction it just won't work.

Comment: You should specify the language; I assume this is Java?

Comment: Floor rounds down, not up.

Comment: Its working. Just checked

Comment: What does "doesn't work" mean.  Crashes?  Won't compile?  Returns 999?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Either of your attempts should work as-is, except that they will give the double value of 4.0 instead of the integer value 4.  If you want to store this as an integer, you could try casting with the following line at the end:

```
int integralNumber = (int)number;
```

**EDIT**: It looks like you are getting an exception.  The value going into `System.in` must not be what you expect, because the code as written works.  You could try the following to find out what the input looks like:

```
package package.name;

import java.util.Scanner;
public class TestingJava
{
  public static void main(String[] args){
    double number;
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Name a number!");
    if(input.hasNextDouble()){
      number = input.nextDouble();
      number = Math.floor(number);
      System.out.println(number);
    } else {
      System.out.println("Expected a double but received " + input.next());
    }
  }
}
```

Another possibility is that the locale is not correct.  The Scanner might be confused about what a decimal point is.  If English is not the default locale, you can try this after initializing the Scanner:

```
input.useLocale(Locale.ENGLISH);
```

Comment: Well the codes I showed you are giving me errors...

Comment: Exception in thread "main" java.util.InputMismatchException
 at java.util.Scanner.throwFor(Unknown Source)
 at java.util.Scanner.next(Unknown Source)
 at java.util.Scanner.nextDouble(Unknown Source)
 at just.testing.TestingJava.main(TestingJava.java:10)

Comment: What input are you using?  That exception is consistent with typing in something other than a number into `System.in`.

Comment: when i type 4.6 or 6.5 etc. it gives me the error.

Comment: Well it still gives me a double... this is what it says:

Comment: Name a number!
4.5
Expected a double but received 4.5

Comment: What does "input.hasNextDouble" mean?

Comment: `input.hasNextDouble()` tests whether or not the next token for the Scanner can be interpreted as a double.  If yours is not interpreting 4.5 correctly, I'm guessing it's because you are using a locale where "4.5" does not mean "4 and 5 tenths."  For instance, I believe your behavior is consistent with the French locale.

Comment: It is definitely not the decimal point confusion because I have used Eclipse alot and it never got confused when I used a dot. It just isn't working with Math.floor or Math.ceil. I find it very weird since it is working for others...

Comment: I suggest you try it before declaring that it's definitely not the issue.

Comment: I am dutch and when I type something like System.out.println(4.3+6.2); it still says 10.5 as an answer.

Comment: Oh, you meant the "input.useLocale(Locale.ENGLISH);" part. I just tested THAT and that works... :S Why does it work outside of the scanner, though? Thanks for your help :D

Comment: Glad you figured it out.  I don't know the details of how locales work, but that might be worth investigating for you.  Note that you can accept an answer if you wish by checking the check mark next to the question.  This is preferable to changing the title to say "Solved."  Welcome to Stack Overflow by the way.

Comment: I just changed my full locale of my Eclipse to English and US as my country. Don't have to worry about this anymore.

Answer (score 0):

In Java, I thought it was

```
Math.Ceil(number);
int num = (int)number;
```

rounded up and floor rounded down?  So, round it up first, and then convert it using (int) to a whole number.

Comment: Well it doesn't matter... Whenever I use Math.ceil or Math.floor it just won't work. Doesn't matter which one I use. And I want to round it down anyways. Android Decoded says it works for him... But it doesn't for me :S

Comment: I'd try debugging, what value is number when it's passed into the ceil function? What happens when you put scanner AFTER the system.out as per this example? http://www.java-made-easy.com/java-scanner.html

Answer (score 0):

Can you give an example of a fraction?

If I ender 1.3 for example I will get an output of 1.0, as expected.  If however enter something like 1/3 I get the error you're seeing, which again I'd expect (as its not a double - it'll probably be a String)

Comment: Nevermind - you answered my question as I was typing my original suggestion